# Issue in setting up Docker container monitroing through zabbix

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have setup a Zabbix Server and a Client. Docker containers are running on Client, I'm unable to retrieve the data for the Containers.

Following error is occuring when I'm checking the status through **zabbix_get** command

[zabbix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzChb.png)

PS: I'm using the official Docker monitoring template from Zabbix

Comment: Please add the error message from the screenshot

Comment: That template requires Zabbix 5.0 and zabbix-agent2. AFAIK no Linux distributions ship either of these at present.

Comment: When referencing text errors, it's always best to copy + paste them in as text, rather than images.